# How to add active class to particular section in React/ Preact application without react-router router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, preact

I am working on preact/react application which does not have routing functionality. We are navigating to particular section by scrolling or clicking link using id of particular section.

I know using react-router I can add active class using NavLink tag. But I want to have same functionality in my case and also need to have scroll-spy functionality in order to change the style if I scroll to particular section.

Sample code would look like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li  style='display:inline'><a href="#firstSection">Section1</a></li>
    <li  style='display:inline'><a href="#secondSection">Section2</a></li>
    <li  style='display:inline'><a href="#thirdSection">Section3</a></li>
  </ul>
<section id='firstSection' style="margin: 300px;">
  This is first section.
</section>
<section id='secondSection' style="margin: 300px;">
  This is Second section.
</section>
<section id='thirdSection' style="margin: 300px;">
  This is Third section.
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if any more info is required.

I would be always grateful to you guys for the help.

Comment: All of your list hrefs currently point at the same end point.

Comment: You want add css class? Where exactly?

Comment: @pmkro thanks for the inputs. I have corrected that.

Comment: @Salah-1 i want to add active class to navigation tab , according to the sample code in Section1, Section2 or Section3 , whichever section i am viewing. so that i can style if i am viewing that section. I can do that in simple html page but same thing i want to add in react/preact application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got that working using Bootstrap Scrollspy plugin via javascript. Below piece of code works perfectly

```
 $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' })
```

and add data-target="#id-of-section-you-want-to-spy" to all the li tags.

This is the refernce link [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#scrollspy).

Answer (score 0):

You could observe `hashchange` event on window, and in callback, set active class to link which href matches `window.location.hash`. You can read more about `hashchange` event here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange

Comment: Thanks Piotr Szlagura .I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Really appreciate you taking the time to reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to target the onClick event of the element like this

```
className={ this.props.isActive ? 'navigation--active': '' }
  onClick={ this.props.onActiveTab }
```

Snippet taken from this related question

[React add class active on selected tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436351/react-add-class-active-on-selected-tab)

Comment: Thank you Salah-1, it seems useful. will try this too.

Comment: It works for onclick event, but How can I implement Scroll spy in react project?